# High-Fidelity UI prototype into Google web based application

Tags: google-apps-script

Hello world (had to do it),

I am new coding, and was hoping to deploy an idea into a usable web-based application using google apps script, then eventually a create a native based app, that functioned like the web-based.

1. If I am utilizing a High-fidelity prototyper, to essentially copy and paste animations into google apps script, will it maintain the design and feel of that high-fidelity prototyper? This particular open source animation library was built to easily translate into production ready environments (called Framer Motion API)
2. Does google app script have the capability to interface into an IOS native operating system? Could the project I built using the web-based, be translated into a functioning native-based with a little bit of work? What is the best way to go about doing this?

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

Please [edit] your question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.